# Force ECS to wait for previous container to have exited before deploying new task version

Tags: amazon-ecs

I have a couple of ECS services that cannot under any circumstances run two instances of a container (embedded elasticsearch, mysql). Is there any way to force ECS to wait until the container has actually stopped (not just transitioned to DEPROVISIONING) before deploying the new task revision?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I recently struggled with this issue as well. Set `deployment_maximum_percent=101` (you can't do `100` because it can't be the same as `deployment_minimum_percent`)